# Programatically close browser or disable all chrome extensions instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need a solution to quit/close browser at some point in application logic. `window.close();` doesn't help me out here as there are cases when several tabs are open, thus I need to close whole browser. I'm not sure if it is entirely possible, as there are indeed security/partical issues here, hence any other solutions or ideas will be appreciated.

This is mainly for stopping certain chrome extensions, maybe there is a way to disable these programatically instead?

Comment: I had to do this for one of my projects. I have searched for long days and I have never found any solution. In the other hand, I prefer this. Allowing this kind of function should be a huge security issue...

Comment: Have you tried "win.close()". I'm not sure if this is still working in recent chrome versions? I know Firefox will only let you close windows opened by a script - with script, not 100% sure about the newest chrome versions.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin See rsanchez answer, it helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [chrome.management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) API provides ways to manage the list of extensions/apps that are installed and running.

In particular, you have the `chrome.management.setEnabled` function, which can programmatically enable or disable a chrome extension.

So, you can write your own extension using this API and specifying the `"management"` permission in the manifest.